# My .htaccess file fails to remove .html extensions

Tags: .htaccess

I'm in the process of tweaking our company website and can't seem to find the right **.htaccess** code **to remove .html extensions** from our pages *(I'm not a coder, I am learning html on my own)*. I'm using this code to remove .html extensions and other things as well *(other things work)*:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews


RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

#removing trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

#www to non
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

#index redirect 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone help? This is getting really frustrating as I've tried more than 5 different variations, all of which don't work!

Thank you.

Comment: read [this topic](https://htaccessbook.com/add-remove-change-file-extensions-htaccess/)  , may help you

Comment: Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to remove `.html` extension use :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724014/htaccess-messing-up-with-php-extension?rq=1) for more